# Is it possible combining concatenate and IF formulas into one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make some sort of spreadsheet for easier note taking (basically a generator of sorts) and I'm having difficulty in trying to find the right way to go at it. I'm basically a total noob at this and just literally started tinkering with Excel and just successfully finished my first IF formula (A little sad, I know, but I'm happy about the progress I've made).

Basically, what I want to do is try to add text from a different cell that would appear before the IF formula.

This is an example of what I have right now:
Cells A1-5 are different animals: Cat, Dog, Fish, Moose

I created a drop list in B1

In C1 I have the IF formula so that whatever is selected in B1 it would appear as such in C1.

What I want to accomplish here is I want to add text that would be taken from different cells so that it would appear before the data in C1.

Like in D1 I would have "It's" and in E1 I would have "A".

What I want to do is that everything I select from the list of animals it would appear as "It's a Cat" "It's a Dog" and so on and so forth in C1. But the thing is I can't find a way to have it done as I want to be able to change the data in D1 and E1 so that it would reflect each time I choose a different animal (I'm sorry if I'm using animals, it was the easiest thing I could think of when practicing the IF formula).

I don't know if what I'm asking is too much, but I'd really like any info regarding this.

Comment: What did you wrote in your If you can write `="It's a " & B1` if you have the result in B1

Comment: It's all cool now. I kinda figured it out haha. I'm currently using =If(B1="Whale",""&D1&""&E1&"Moby Dick","") so now whatever I put into D1 and E1 it would appear as such once I select a particular animal. The animals are just to test it out as I found it easier to use them. I'm currently finding out a way on how to effectively do note taking using the said formula since all the responses are the same, it's just I needed a way to change the text before the said note.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `="It's a " & B1` and you will get `It's a Cat` or any other animal (or whatever).

Comment: The thing is, I need to change the "It's a" part every now and then. Again, this was just simplified to make things easier to understand. Basically, I need the text before the animal to be editable on the get go. Thanks for your suggestions and comments!

Comment: If you have the animal in cell B1, `It's` in cell C1, and `a` in cell D1, you can get all together in E1 by using formula `=C1 & " " & D1 & " " &B1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below formula

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A4>A5,A6&" ",A7&" "),"Cat")
```

where A6 and A7 have the condition result and A4 and A5 are the values to compare.